# login not working,while registering is

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have done enough researching ,when logging in it does not redirect me to the resource page in case of correct password also.. i had tried SHA1 on passwords before but first dealing with simpler cases,i removed it.
when i ask NAME = '$usr',
As i have user as username,
if i enter User too,it doenot show wrong username,on terminal also if we try this,for username 'user' or 'User',it shows the same thing.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","*****");
    session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
    {
            if (!$con)
            {
                    die("OOPS!Could not connect to server".mysql_error());
            }
                    $passwd = $_POST['password'];
                    $usr=$_POST['username'];
                    mysql_select_db('USERS',$con) or die(mysql_error());
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT PASSWD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='$usr'",$con) Or die(mysql_error());
                    $pass = mysql_result($result,0);
                    if ($pass==$passwd) {
                            header('Location : resource.html');}
                    else
                            {echo "sorry $usr wrong username or password"; }

    }
else if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
    {
            $usr = $_POST['user'];
            $passwd = $_POST['password1'];
            $name = $_POST['fullname'];
            mysql_select_db('USERS',$con) or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='$usr'",$con) Or die(mysql_error());
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($num==0) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(NAME,USERNAME,PASSWD) VALUES('$name','$usr','$passwd')");
            echo "congrats! you have been added.Go back to resources and log in";
            }
            else echo "Someone already has that username. Go back and try with another username";
    }

 mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: add `semicolon` at the end of the line above `echo "congrats...`

Comment: Please don't use that code on a live webserver - you're open to SQL injection attacks. Never, ever, pass $_POST array elements directly to MySql without escaping them properly.

Comment: You see i am just a week old to the world of html/php. can you please elaborate and suggest something more please..

Comment: Here's the more complete version: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Madara but this is my homework problem,and i need to use mysql.. :(

Comment: @sum: Go and tell your teacher that Madara Uchiha said he's teaching crap. ext/mysql is almost ***almost*** as old as IE6. Hopefully film it and upload to youtube, so that I can enjoy it too :D

Comment: @Madara :D can't tell him that.

Comment: @sum: Sure you can. If he asks, bring him to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a semicolon before an echo

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(NAME,USERNAME,PASSWD) VALUES('$name','$usr','$passwd')");//<-- right here
echo "congrats! you have been added.Go back to resources and log in";
```

Also you are not sanitizing your user input, look into prepared statements ([PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php))

Comment: right done that..but now still after adding that and entering username,passwd it doesnt redirect me to resource.html (if(submit1) code for login,not registering)

Comment: @sum use `header('Location: resource.html');` to redirect

Comment: tried this but still a blank page appears. no redirection

Comment: using echo "<script type=''text/javascript>window.location='resource.html'</script>" did the job.:)